# iPad Photo Gallery Framework

Tags: ios, ipad, frameworks, photo-gallery

I am looking for some framework that allows me to create a Photo Gallery that allows the user to swipe through pictures, and then select one and it takes them to a specific view based on that image. I seen this idea in another App, and didnt know if this was an open source framework, or if there is anything similar.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a library that should be able to handle this:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Check out the "custom" or "time machine" carousels in the example app for something similar to what you've shown.

Here's a screenshot. Don't worry that it's not exactly the same as your picture; the angle, panel size, etc. can all be configured.

[image]

Comment: Very nice work on this framework. It does exactly what I need. Thank you so much.